# How to return original page from customer CGI Handler?

Tags: cgi, apache2.4

I am trying to intercept each and every request using python CGI handler to particular path in Apache 2.4 server and modify the original as required. (This is to validate JWT token stored in cookie)

I am referring the below documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/handler.html)

> Modifying static content using a CGI script The following directives
>   will cause requests for files with the html extension to trigger the
>   launch of the footer.pl CGI script.
>
> `Action add-footer /cgi-bin/footer.pl` 
>   `AddHandler add-footer .html`
>
> Then the CGI script is responsible for sending the originally
>   requested document (pointed to by the PATH_TRANSLATED environment
>   variable) and making whatever modifications or additions are desired.

I am able to reach the handler and validate the JWT token in it.
But, the issue is I don't find a way to sent the original document when the token is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not be using a handler for this task.  If you must write your extension in an interpreted language, look at a `RewriteMap prg:` extension point.  Otheriwse, you can write code in a hook meant for access control.

But in the example you show, the injected handler would only work for a static file  request. It's just going to something akin to `cat`'ing the file passes as an argument then writing its own trailing data.